# NetBeans hangs on attempting to use "find usage"

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

```
Netbeans version tried: 7.3 and 7.2.1
OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Java Version: 1.6.0_27
```

I am getting weird problems using NetBeans. The problem in the title is one out of many, and maybe they are all related.

To resolve this problem, I just like to know if anyone else is encountering the same/similar problem in the environment described. Can anyone provide any resolution to the problem(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a JDK issue. I resolved my problem by updating to latest JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Just rollback for jdk packages:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk=6b24-1.11.4-3ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre=6b24-1.11.4-3ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless=6b24-1.11.4-3ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-lib=6b24-1.11.4-3ubuntu1
```

Comment: Actually doing the reverse helped, that is getting updated JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the cause in your case but I found this, having the same issue on Mac OS with Netbeans 8.0.2: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236101
They say it's a bug in JDK 7u40.

I can confirm that installing JDK 8 fixes this.